# No module named PyQt5 windows 8.1 x64

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt

I want to transform .ui to .py to start coding but when I asked command line and typed:

```
python 'qt path' 'form_name'.ui -o 'form_name'.py
```

I got an error "No module named PyQt5".

[image: Here is a cmd screen of an error]

Comment: Do you have another other version of Python installed?  If you just do `python` and then try `from PyQt5 import QtCore` from within the Python interpreter, what happens?

Comment: What is the output of `echo %PATH%` and `echo %PYTHONPATH%`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt and typing pip install PyQt5

CMD > pip install PYQT5

Comment: If you look at the screenshot, you can see that there's already a path to a PyQt5 package. Chances are that whoever asked the question may have already installed PyQt5--possibly by the very method that you suggested.